# Golang: interface func to print memory address

Tags: pointers, memory, go, struct, interface

I am curious as to why just printing the memory address on a var directly works but trying to do the same action through an interface doesn't print out the memory address?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type address struct {
    a int
}

type this interface {
    memory()
}

func (ad address) memory() {
    fmt.Println("a - ", ad)
    fmt.Println("a's memory address --> ", &ad)
}

func main() {
    ad := 43
    fmt.Println("a - ", ad)
    fmt.Println("a's memory address --> ", &ad)

    //code init in here
    thisAddress := address{
        a: 42,
    }
    // not sure why this doesnt return memory address as well?
    var i this
    i = thisAddress
    i.memory()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ko8sEVfehv

Just wanted to add this after fixing errors, it now functions as expected.
Testing shifting memory pointers

```
package main

import "fmt"

type address struct {
  a int
}

type this interface {
  memory() *int
}

func (ad address) memory() *int {

  /*reflect.ValueOf(&ad).Pointer() research laws of reflection */
  var b = &ad.a

  return b
}

func main() {



  thisAddress := address{
      a: 42,
  }
  thatAddress := address{
      a: 43,
  }

  var i this
  i = thisAddress
  a := i.memory()

  fmt.Println("I am retruned", a)
  fmt.Println("I am retruned", *a)
  i = thatAddress
  c := i.memory()
  fmt.Println("I am retruned", c)
  fmt.Println("I am retruned", *c)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BnB14-yX8B

Comment: You should use the `reflect` package in this case. `reflect.ValueOf(&ad).Pointer()` will return &ad (which is a pointer value) as `uintptr`.

Comment: Thank you, just looked up reflect am now reading laws of reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your second case inside the `memory()` method:

```
func (ad address) memory() {
    fmt.Println("a - ", ad)
    fmt.Println("a's memory address --> ", &ad)
}
```

`ad` is not an `int` but a struct, `ad` is of type `address`. And you're not printing the address of an `int` but an address of a `struct`. And the default formatting for pointer to a struct is: `&{}`.

Quoting from package doc of [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) regarding default formats:

> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

If you modify the line to print the address of the `address.a` field which is of type `int`:

```
fmt.Println("a's memory address --> ", &ad.a)
```

You will see the same pointer format printed in hexadecimal format, e.g.:

```
a's memory address -->  0x1040e13c
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and they worked exactly as I how I wanted this too thank you, for that concise answer.