# Go struct method allows type mixing?

Tags: go

I have a simple struct with a single method:

```
type Person struct {
  name string
}

func (p Person) SetName(name string) {
  p.name = name
}
```

the output of the following:

```
dave := Person{}
dave.SetName("Dave")
fmt.Println(dave.name)
```

is going to be empty because the method receiver accepts a value(or more accurately creates a copy of the value you pass) so it will not modify your underlying value.

If I change the method to this:

```
func (p *Person) SetName(name string) {
  p.name = name
}
```

the output will be "Dave".

Now what I don't understand is am I not supposed to call the method on a pointer?
So when initialing my object I should do this:

```
dave := &Person{}
```

instead of this:

```
dave := Person{}
```

Also using go's reflect package I was trying to find out the value of:

```
&Person
```

and found it to be *Person, which is fine. When I print the value though I don't get a memory location compared to when I print the value of a pointer to an int:

```
a := 4
fmt.Println(&a)
```

I keep reading the docs, asking questions on so but the more I learn the more I wonder if I'm missing something simple since a lot of people don't think all this is confusing.

Comment: See related / possible duplicates: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956290/pointer-methods-on-non-pointer-types/46956348#46956348), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477951/what-is-the-method-set-of-sync-waitgroup/42480671#42480671), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481420/calling-a-method-with-a-pointer-receiver-by-an-object-instead-of-a-pointer-to-it/38481697#38481697).

Comment: Thanks for these. Makes my question sort of a duplicate but at least the bit about addresses is unique.

Comment: That's also a duplicate of other questions...

Comment: Can you find one? I can't seem to find anything on it. Even more confusing i can get the address of a struct object by getting a pointer to the pointer

Comment: The last part is a duplicate of [Golang: interface func to print memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739743/golang-interface-func-to-print-memory-address/39740087#39740087); also see [Difference between golang pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039827/difference-between-golang-pointers/42042673#42042673).

Comment: I see. So its not like the value is not an address but fmt formats differently. Thanks for these

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing calling a method on a pointer receiver with keeping a pointer to a value. That is, there is no *inherent* connection between calling `SetName` defined on a pointer receiver with the requirement to store a pointer to a memory holding a value of type `Person` vs storing `Person` directly.

When you have the declaration

```
var pers Person
```

and then call

```
pers.SetName("foo")
```

the compiler takes the address of the memory block occupied by the
variable `pers`—just like if you were doing that by hand through applying
the `&` operator to `pers`, and passes that address to the `SetName`
function, so the call ends up being done like

```
(&pers).SetName("foo")
```

or, to say it differently, the `SetName`'s receiver will be
`&pers`—that is, the address of `pers`.

Now there's nothing preventing you from taking the address of `pers`
and storing it elsewhere:

```
var ptr *Person = &pers
```

(you usually do not write such Java-style stuttering code but
I'm doing this for extra clarity), and now you're able to call
`SetName` right on the `ptr` value:

```
ptr.SetName("bar")
```

Now the compiler will directly use the value stored in the variable `ptr`
to pass it as the method's receiver.

The final bit of this "puzzle" is that when you use
the special syntax provided by Go—applying the address-taking operator `&`
directly to a literal,—the compiler does something like this:

```
var __pers Person = Person{
    // The contents of your literal
}
var dave = &__pers
```

…and makes the `__pers` variable inaccessible by name (since it naturally
has no name).

As you can see, this is no different from getting the pointer
to a `Person` value's memory by hand.

---

You might want to consult [this FAQ entry](https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets) to gain more understanding
of how the method sets on a type `T` and `*T` relate, and why the latter
always includes the former but not vice-versa.
Also read [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers).

---

*Update:* to explain the difference in how `fmt.Println` formats and outputs
the values of type `*int` and `*Person`.

- The former is printed as the base-16 string representation
  of an address of a memory location containing that `int` value.
- The latter is rendered using a string representation resembling
  Go's syntax for taking a pointer to a literal: `&{}`.

This behaviour is as documented: `fmt.Print` and `fmt.Println`
use the so-called default formatting rules for the arguments they
are passed, and these rules depend on the types of the arguments.

Let's first consult the documentation on `fmt.Println`
(run `go doc fmt.Println`):

> `func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`
>
> `Println` formats *using the default formats for its operands*
>   and writes to standard output.
>   Spaces are always added between operands and a newline is appended.
>   It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.

(Emphasis mine.)

Now let's turn to the documentation of the `fmt` package itself
(run `go doc fmt`):

> <…>
>
> Printing
>
> The verbs:
>
> General:
>
> - `%v` the value in a default format
>
>   when printing structs, the plus flag (`%+v`) adds field names.
>
> <…>
>
> The default format for `%v` is:
>
> ```
> bool:                    %t
> int, int8 etc.:          %d
> uint, uint8 etc.:        %d, %#x if printed with %#v
> float32, complex64, etc: %g
> string:                  %s
> chan:                    %p
> pointer:                 %p
> ```
>
> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules,
>   recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

A `*Person` is a pointer to a struct type, so it's rendered as

```
&{name}
```

where `name` is the contents of the name field; say, if it was assigned
the string "Dave", the output would be `&{dave}`.

Comment: you are saying that a pointer receiver type variable points to different address while when we use it as argument it points to different address

Comment: Explain the last part of the question about `*int` being printed as an address but not `*Person` and it'll be complete.

Comment: Very good explanation. I sort of guessed that go does the conversion for you. Please explain the last bit about printing the memory address so that I can accept this as the correct answer

Comment: @Himanshu, I failed to parse this; care to elaborate? May be in a few more simple sentences.